# How can I create an Incident with attachment in Remedy9

Tags: php, rest, remedy

I am working on Remedy9 API integration with my code. I want to create incidents with attachment. I am using Rest APIs for the same. I am able to create incident without attachment but I have no idea how to do it with attachment.

I have written my code in php. Can someone help?

Comment: have you read through their documentation?